# How to nest dictionary and list to a dictionary through a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have problems understanding how to nest dictionaries automatically. In the script, I need a dictionary that holds dictionaries that holds a list. Like This:

```py
week{
    1:{
        m: [],
        l: [],
        d: []
    },
    2:{
        m: [],
        l: [],
        d: []
    },
    # ...
}
```

What I have Tried:

```py
commands = ["m", "ml", "l", "ld", "d"] # want to use them as keys
week = {}
for d in range(7):
    d += 1
    week[d] = {}
    for t in commands:
        day = {}
        day[t] = []
        week[d] = day
print(week)

# Output:
{1: {'d': []}, 2: {'d': []}, 3: {'d': []}, 4: {'d': []}, 5: {'d': []}, 6: {'d': []}, 7: {'d': []}}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating `day` dictionary in `for t in commands` loop. Try to do like this:

```
week[d] = {}  # Let this line to be 1
day = {}
for t in commands:
    day[t] = []
week[d] = day # If you wrote this line, you don`t need line 1 anymore
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for t in commands:
    day = {}
    day[t] = []
    week[d] = day
```

Here you are creating a new sub-dictionary for each of the keys in `command`. You should only create one dictionary for each key in `week`, which is what you are doing the line before:

```
week[d] = {}
```

In the inner for loop, all you need to do is to add to the dictionary `week[d]`:

```
for t in commands:
    week[d][t] = []
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
commands = ["m", "ml", "l", "ld", "d"]
weeks = {}

for d in range(1,8):
    weeks[d] = {com:[] for com in commands}

print(json.dumps(weeks,indent=4))

{
    "1": {
        "m": [],
        "ml": [],
        "l": [],
        "ld": [],
        "d": []
    },
    "2": {
        "m": [],
        "ml": [],
        "l": [],
        "ld": [],
        "d": []
    },
    "3": {
        "m": [],
        "ml": [],
        "l": [],
        "ld": [],
        "d": []
    },
    "4": {
        "m": [],
        "ml": [],
        "l": [],
        "ld": [],
        "d": []
    },
    "5": {
        "m": [],
        "ml": [],
        "l": [],
        "ld": [],
        "d": []
    },
    "6": {
        "m": [],
        "ml": [],
        "l": [],
        "ld": [],
        "d": []
    },
    "7": {
        "m": [],
        "ml": [],
        "l": [],
        "ld": [],
        "d": []
    }
}
```